# error when passing attribute to a layout from included layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, layout, android-include

In order to make my app code cleaner, I try to create common xml but I am getting an error like below:

```
error: activity_login.xml:230: AAPT: error: attribute buttonTitle
```

In my Login.xml file:

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        layout="@layout/widget_large_button"
        app:buttonTitle="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

and I have defined the layout as below:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="buttonTitle"
        type="String"/>
</data>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/stripe_backgound_05"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:letterSpacing="0.5"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:text="@{buttonTitle}"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/gainsboro_05"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

It seems that I can't pass the buttonTitle from the login.xml to the button widget.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just try changing variable type from String to CharSequence.

Comment: it's still not working. It's not coming from the type. It's really coming from the linking between the 2 layout

Comment: Can you pass the string like: app:buttonTitle="@{@string/login}"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `bind:buttonTitle="@{'variable name of login.xml'}"`  in the include tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).